# Error creating bean with name securityConfig.AdminSecurityConfiguration Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

Hi am using spring security configuration file for two login screen(user and admin) so i used separate configuration annotation(order1 and order2) with same security config class,and am using the  two different User Details tables for both(admin,user) login credential.

i have attached the SecurityConfig, MyUserDetailsService and MyAdminDetailsService java file

```
 Securityconfig.java


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{   


     @Configuration
     @Order(1)
     public static class UserSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
     {
         public UserSecurityConfiguration() 
         {
                super();
         }
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired 
        AuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticatonSuccessHandler;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
        {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
        {
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable().
                    authorizeRequests()


                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
                    .antMatchers("/User_Control/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN ACCESS')or hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
                    .antMatchers("/AccountSetting/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
                    .antMatchers("/Farm/**","/Shed/**","/Item/**","/Customer/**","/Supplier/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
                    .antMatchers("/Company/**","/General/**","/User_Control/**","/Contact/**","/Listofcharts/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
                    .antMatchers("/Strain/**","/Strain_Master/**","/Feed_Formulation/**","/Vaccination/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
                    .antMatchers("/Batch_Register/**","/Batch_Arrival/**","/Batch_Transfer_Register/**","/Batch_Transfer/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
                    .antMatchers("/Mortality_Register/**","/Mortality_Transaction/**","/Feed_Register/**","/Feed_Transaction/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")
                    .antMatchers("/Egg_Register/**","/Egg_Transaction/**","/Cull_Register/**","/Cull_Transaction/**","/Vaccine_Register/**","/Vaccine_Report_Transaction/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS')")

                    .antMatchers("/","/dashboard/**").access("hasRole('FULL ACCESS') or hasRole('LIMITTED ACCESS')or hasRole('ADMIN ACCESS')")

                    .and()              
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").successHandler(customAuthenticatonSuccessHandler)           
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")              
                    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").invalidateHttpSession(true)           
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .permitAll()

                    .and().csrf()   
                      .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")       
                      .and()
                      .sessionManagement()

                      .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
                        .invalidSessionUrl("/login?invalid")                        
                        .maximumSessions(1)                                                         
                            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                            .expiredUrl("/login?expired")                                   
                            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception 
        {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }


        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
        {
            PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();      
            return encoder;
        }
        @Bean(name = "sessionRegistry")
        public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() 
        {
          return new SessionRegistryImpl();
        }

        @Autowired
        private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

        public List<SessionInformation> getActiveSessions() 
        {
            List<SessionInformation> activeSessions = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) 
            {
                    activeSessions.addAll(sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false));
            }
            return activeSessions;
        }
     }



     @Configuration
     @Order(2)
     public static class AdminSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
     {
         public AdminSecurityConfiguration() 
         {
                super();
         }
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("adminDetailsService")
        public UserDetailsService adminDetailsService;

        @Autowired 
        AuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticatonSuccessHandler;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
        {
            auth.userDetailsService(adminDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
        {
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable().
                        authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN ACCESS')")
                        .antMatchers("/","/dashboard/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN ACCESS')")
                        .and()              
                        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").successHandler(customAuthenticatonSuccessHandler)           
                        .usernameParameter("username")
                        .passwordParameter("password")              
                        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").invalidateHttpSession(true)           
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .permitAll()
                        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403") 
                        .and().csrf().disable()         
                        .sessionManagement()
                        .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
                        .invalidSessionUrl("/login?invalid")                        
                        .maximumSessions(1)                                                         
                        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                        .expiredUrl("/login?expired")                                   
                        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        }


        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
        {
            PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();      
            return encoder;
        }
//      
        @Bean(name = "sessionRegistry")
        public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() 
        {
          return new SessionRegistryImpl();
        }



     }   


}




MyAdminDetailsService.java


@Service("adminDetailsService")
public class MyAdminDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    private AdminUserDao adminUserDao;

    @Autowired
    private AdminRolePrivilegeDao adminRolePrivilegeDao;

    String username;
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        //com.broman.model.m_user m_user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
        com.broman.admin.AdminUserModel adminuser1=adminUserDao.findByUserName(username);
        int userid=adminuser1.getId();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(adminRolePrivilegeDao.geta(userid));
        return buildUserForAuthentication(adminuser1, authorities);
    }



    private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.broman.admin.AdminUserModel adminuser1, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities)
    {
        return new User(adminuser1.getAdmin_username(), adminuser1.getAdmin_password(),authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(List<AdminRolePrivilegeModel> adminUserRoles)
    {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        // Build user's authorities
        for (AdminRolePrivilegeModel userRole : adminUserRoles)
        {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getAdminrole_name()));

        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return Result;
    }

}




**MyUserDetailsService.java**

package com.broman.service;
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{

    @Autowired
    private UsersDao usersDao;

    @Autowired
    private UserPrivilegeDao userprivilegeDao;


    String username;
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        //com.broman.model.m_user m_user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
        com.broman.setting.usercontrol.User user1=usersDao.findByUserName(username);
        int userid=user1.getUser_id();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(userprivilegeDao.geta(userid));
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user1, authorities);
    }


    // org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
    private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.broman.setting.usercontrol.User user1, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities)
    {
        return new User(user1.getUsername(), user1.getUserpassword(),authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(List<UserPrivilege> userRoles)
    {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        // Build user's authorities
        for (UserPrivilege userRole : userRoles)
        {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole_name()));

        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return Result;
    }

}
```

After compile i got following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig.AdminSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.broman.config.SecurityConfig$AdminSecurityConfiguration.adminDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.broman.admin.AdminRolePrivilegeDao com.broman.service.MyAdminDetailsService.adminRolePrivilegeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.broman.admin.AdminRolePrivilegeDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

am getting this error so long  any one can provide solution for this problem.

Comment: post your stacktrace please